# select dates between two unix timestamps

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the table users.

Columns:

- user_id - integer
- user_date - integer(unix timestamp)

Some of rows have user_date and some have NULL.

I need to find all user_id's which user_date includes period between '2012-10-21' and '2012-10-24'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_date BETWEEN
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2012-10-21') AND
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM date '2012-10-24' + interval '1 day');
```

If you don't want the end date to be included, remove the bit adding a day to that.

Comment: Why there is a + interval '1 day' is there? Is Postgres SQL act different for BETWEEN?

Comment: @YasiruG Since the `user_date` field is a timestamp if a day isn't added to the end of the range, it would only include users added in the first second of the ending date.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from users
where 
    timestamp 'epoch' + user_date * interval '1 second' between '2012-10-21' and '2012-10-24' 
    and
    user_date is not null
```

Comment: Be careful with those implicit date conversions!

Comment: Seems like you'd want to convert both parameters to an integer, so you could use an index on `user_date`, correct?